# LibGdx Shader ("no uniform with name 'u_texture' in shader")

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, libgdx, glsl, shader

The Shader compiles successfully, but the program crashes as soon as rendering starts... This is the error i get: "no uniform with name 'u_texture' in shader". This is what my shader looks like:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform float time;
uniform vec2 mouse;
uniform vec2 resolution;
varying vec2 surfacePosition;


#define MAX_ITER 10
void main( void ) {

    vec2 p = surfacePosition*4.0;
    vec2 i = p;
    float c = 0.0;
    float inten = 1.0;

    for (int n = 0; n < MAX_ITER; n++) {
        float t = time * (1.0 - (1.0 / float(n+1)));
        i = p + vec2(
            cos(t - i.x) + sin(t + i.y), 
            sin(t - i.y) + cos(t + i.x)
        );
        c += 1.0/length(vec2(
            p.x / (sin(i.x+t)/inten),
            p.y / (cos(i.y+t)/inten)
            )
        );
    }
    c /= float(MAX_ITER);

    gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(pow(c,1.5))*vec3(0.99, 0.97, 1.8), 1.0);
}
```

Can someone please help me. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. BTW, this is shader i found on the internet, so I know it is working, the only problem is making it work with libgdx.

Comment: Isn't this error pretty clear? Libgdx uses uniform variable `u_texture` for something and your shader must have it.

Comment: I figured as much, but even after adding it the error remains the same

Comment: Are you sure that the error is same? And how exactly you added this variable?

Comment: I just added uniform sampler2D u_texture; in the shader program

Answer (score 8, accepted):

libGDX's SpriteBatch assumes that your shader will have `u_texture` uniform. To overcome just add 
`ShaderProgram.pedantic = false;`[(Javadoc)](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShaderProgram.html#pedantic) before putting your shader program into the SpriteBatch.

UPDATE: raveesh is right about shader compiler vanishing unused uniforms and attributes, but libGDX wraps OpenGL shader in custom ShaderProgram.

Answer (score 2):

Not only should you add the uniform u_texture in your shader program, you should also use it, otherwise it will be optimized away by the shader compiler.
But looking at you shader, you don't seem to need the uniform anyway, so check your program for something like `shader.setUniformi("u_texture", 0);` and remove the line. It should work fine then.